# com.facebook.react.common.javascriptexception : unexpected token ‘export’

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, babeljs

i am using React Native 0.59.3 after i install package react-native-background-timer it given me error like that.

com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException : Unexpected token ‘export’

And

unexpected reserved word use ‘class’

Anyone can help me ?

[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0JDN.jpg)
[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bomMo.jpg)

Comment: Instead of adding camera's clicked photo please add the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, its on another phone, so i choose to my camera phone. And i just write an error in description. Images is for additional.

Comment: Try adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 and restart your pc